# How to allow only doc and pdf type in UIDocumentMenuViewController iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentpickervc

I tried to load some files from Dropbox/G-Drive/iCloud using the `UIDocumentMenuViewController`. I tried,

```
UIDocumentMenuViewController *importMenu = [[UIDocumentMenuViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[(__bridge NSString*)kUTTypeContent] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeImport];
importMenu.delegate = self;
importMenu.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:importMenu animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with this to get this done. But I need to get only the **doc** and **pdf** types only from picker. But when I use `kUTTypeContent`, this allows for images and videos also. Is there a way to allow this picker only for doc and pdf(custom types) or is there a why to prevent media files? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for this from [apple developer site](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html). There's a type called `kUTTypeCompositeContent` which is support only for all document types like doc, pdf, xls etc.

> **public.composite-content:(kUTTypeCompositeContent)**
>
> Base type for mixed content. For example, a PDF file contains both text and special formatting data.

Comment: Images are also visible.